# Nest home/away state in iOS

Tags: ios, nest-api

While changing nest state to away for structure it works fine but when we change it as home then it shows below error in iOS firebase sdk. How can we solve this problem? We've have already given away read/write permission in nest developer console. setValue: or removeValue: at /structures/Z62_BmXgHvsJ7SRS6g167jbylqXCDjaYenj-tf2AUkeR_facLyp-kw/home failed: No write permission(s) for field(s): home

Comment: Try getting a new token after updating your permissions.

Comment: we have already given permissions for Home @urman